# I wrote the following code in pineScript, but it is giving a logic error

Tags: pine-script

At a given moment, plot(dev_from_avgP) is returning 0.00, however, according to plot(test), the return is close + 0.5. How is this possible?!

My code:

```
avgPricePos = strategy.position_avg_price
dev_from_avgP = avgP_mult \* ta.stdev(avgPricePos, avgP_len)
top = avgPricePos + dev_from_avgP
bottom = avgPricePos - dev_from_avgP
test = dev_from_avgP == 0 ? close - 0.5 : close + 0.5
plot(test)
plot(dev_from_avgP)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
dev_from_avgP = avgP_mult \* ta.stdev(avgPricePos, avgP_len)
```

There seems to be one more character

> \

Try this:

```
dev_from_avgP = avgP_mult * ta.stdev(avgPricePos, avgP_len)
```